# Provide internal list access via named array

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class that has an internal list of other objects like so:

```
public class Parent
{
    List<Child> _children;
}
```

where Child say looks like this:

```
public class Child
{
    public string Name;
}
```

What I want to do is set up parent where the members of _children can be accessed like so:

```
...
Child kid = parentInstance["Billy"]; // would find a Child instance 
                                     // whose name value is Billy
...
```

Is this possible?  I could obviously do something like this:

```
Child kid = parentInstance.GetChild("Billy");
```

But I prefer the array/dictionary like syntax.  This isn't a big deal if it isn't, and I don't want to have to jump through a million hoops for what amounts to syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could define an [indexed property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288464(VS.71).aspx) to the `Parent` class:

```
public class Parent
{
    List<Child> _children;

    public Child this[string name] 
    {
        get
        {
            return (_children ?? Enumerable.Empty<Child>())
                .Where(c => c.Name == name)
                .FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn my slow typing skills :(

Comment: Dammit.  However long they make you wait before accepting an answer now is still too long...  :)

Comment: Should note that if you have two children with the same name you are SOL in accessing the second one.

Comment: Yeah, for this particular code, I enforce that each name be unique.  :)  would be impossible to access second member without that.

Answer (score 0):

The "array syntax" is not best suited for what you need, and it's rather obsolete too :)

Nowadays in .net we have Linq and the lambda extension methods, that make our life when working with collections really easy.

You can do:

```
IEnumerable<Child> childs = parentInstance.Childrens.Where(child => child.Name == "Billy"); //this will get all childs named billy

Child child = parentInstance.Childrens.FirstOrDefault(child => child.Name == "Billy"); //this will get the first child named billy only, or null if no billy is found
```

You can also write the above queries in linq syntax instead of lambda. For instance, the first query will be like this:

```
IEnumerable<Child> childs = from child in parentInstance.Childrens where child.Name == "billy" select child;
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm familiar with linq, love it, and use the piss out of it.  For what you propose to work, though, I'd have to expose the _children list, which I want to avoid.  (Notice that _children is private in the original code.)

Comment: The question was not about the best method suited to find an item in a list. He specifically asked about "array syntax" or indexers.

Comment: I know he requested "array syntax" but I think that suggesting a possible better way of doing things isn't a crime.

Comment: @Tim, you can expose the children as an IEnumerable property, which allows all the LINQy goodness without compromising encapsulation.  I prefer this over an indexer syntax, generally, as parent["Billy"] is not as natural of an idiom to me (is Billy the child, the grandparent, the uncle?)